# HIVE, HBASE which one I have to use for My Data Analytics

Tags: mysql, hadoop, cassandra, hive, hbase

I have 150 GB of MySQL data, Plan to replace MySQL to Casandra as backend.
Analytics, plan to go with Hadoop, HIVE or HBASE. 
Currently I have 4 physical machines for POC. Please some one help me to come up with best efficient architecture. 
Per day I will get 5 GB of Data.

1. Daily Status report I have to send to each customer.
2. Have to give Analysis report based on request : for example : 1 week report or last month first 2 week report.  Is it possible to produce report instantly using HIVe or HBASE ?
3. I want to give best performance using Cassandra, Hadoop .

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop can process your data using map reduce paradigm or other, using emerging technologies such as Spark. The advantage is a reliable distributed filesystem and the usage of data locality to send the computation to the nodes that have the data.

Hive is a good SQL-like way of processing files and generate your reports once a day. It's batch processing and 5 more GB a day shouldn't produce a big impact. It has a high overhead latency though, but shouldn't be a problem if you do it once a day.

HBase and Cassandra are NoSQL databases whose purpose is to serve data with low latency. If that's a requirement, you should go with any of those. HBase uses the DFS to store the data and Cassandra has good connectors to Hadoop, so it's simple to run jobs consuming from these two sources.

For reports based on request, specifying a date range, you should store the data in an efficient way so you don't have to ingest data that's not needed for your report. Hive supports partitioning and that can be done using date (i.e. `/<year>/<month>/<day>/`). Using partitioning can significantly optimize your job execution times.

If you go to the NoSQL approach, be sure the rowkeys have some date format as prefix (e.g. 20140521...) so that you can select those that start by the dates you want.

Some questions you should also consider are:

- how many data do you want to store in your cluster – e.g. last 180
  days, etc. This will affect the number of nodes / disks. Beware data is usually replicated 3 times.
- how many files do you have in HDFS – when the number of files is high,
  Namenode will be hit hard on retrieval of file metadata. Some
  solutions exist such as replicated namenode or using MapR Hadoop
  distribution which doesn't rely on a Namenode per se.